# VPN that tunnels traffic across multiple, simultaneous connections?

Tags: privacy, vpn, vpn-server

Most VPNs work by establishing a single connection between the client and server and tunneling all traffic through that connection. For example, an OpenVPN client might make a TCP connection to a server listening on 1.1.1.1:443. If this connection is broken, a new connection must be made and a new tunnel established.

In some conditions this is problematic - imagine a network adversary who spoofs TCP resets whenever it detects a new VPN connection. It seems as if one could create a more resilient VPN tunnel by using multiple connections. So the client could make two connections to intermediary servers at 2.2.2.2:443 and 3.3.3.3:443, then split the VPN tunnel traffic across both connections. The intermediary servers would forward that traffic to the endpoint server at 1.1.1.1 (and would forward response traffic back to the client). That way, if either connection goes down, the tunnel will remain up.

I've done some searching, but haven't found any VPNs that use this sort of setup. The closest thing I found was [Tor Snowflake](https://snowflake.torproject.org/), but if I'm reading that correctly even though the system rotates IPs rapidly, only one connection is actually used at aany given time.

Any recommendations? Am I missing some sort of key search term? Or does this type of VPN simply not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDWAN/Overlay Networking is likely going to get you there, Nebula was designed by Slack, https://github.com/slackhq/nebula to provide secure software defined networking,to connect multiple sites P2P.

There are other SDWAN/Overlay products, but Nebula is free.

In detail overview https://youtu.be/qy2cgqglt3o

SDWAN will actually combine multiple pipes into a single, and use them both simultaneously, if on goes down your connection is up, and than the other comes back up, the redundancy is restored. Now in this case, it would not be able to do anything with the fact a physical route went down, but it would allow you to treat two connections as a single and NOT drop as longs as one of them were up.

That said, VPNs should not just *drop* unless their are connectivity issues, or idle timeouts.